# chef git :sync UnresolvableGitReference

Tags: git, github, chef-infra, chef-solo

I am facing a strange issue with git resource in chef. I am getting the `UnresolvableGitReference` error even though the repository and the tag exists.

compiled resource in the recipe:

    `git("/opt/some-repo") do
      action [:sync]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      destination "/opt/some-repo"
      enable_checkout true
      revision "tags/v3.0.4"
      remote "origin"
      checkout_branch "deploy"
      declared_type :git
      cookbook_name :"some-cookbook"
      recipe_name "install"
      user "ubuntu"
      repository "git@github.com:someUser/some-repo.git"
    end`

The instance can access the git repo and the reference.

`git ls-remote 'git@github.com:someUser/some-repo.git' 'tags/v3.0.4*'` returns me the commit id.

The cookbook works fine in chef v11.8.2 however fails in chef v12.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `git` resource you can use only the tag name `'v3.0.4'`. If you need to specify that it is a tag, you can also use the full path: `'refs/tags/v3.0.4'`.

This worked before because [Chef 11 checks against the reference sufix](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/11.18.14/lib/chef/provider/git.rb#L263):

```ruby
found = refs.find { |m| m[1].end_with?(@new_resource.revision) }
```

But this can be problematic as you might imagine. I think `'tags/v3.0.4'` to work was never an expected behavior.

Anyway, [in Chef 12 the implementation has changed](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/12.6.0/lib/chef/provider/git.rb#L262-L275), and now searches by prefix, appending `'ref/tags/'` and `'refs/heads/'` to search for tags and branches respectively:

```ruby
def find_revision(refs, revision, suffix="")
  found = refs_search(refs, rev_match_pattern('refs/tags/', revision) + suffix)
  found = refs_search(refs, rev_match_pattern('refs/heads/', revision) + suffix) if found.empty?
  found = refs_search(refs, revision + suffix) if found.empty?
  found
end

def rev_match_pattern(prefix, revision)
  if revision.start_with?(prefix)
    revision
  else
    prefix + revision
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I played around a bit and found out the issue. the `tag` of a git repo for **property** `revision` need not be preceded by `tags/`. I don't know in which version of chef it changed but, I confirm that it worked in chef version `11.8.2`.

Therefore `revision "tags/v3.0.4"` changes to `revision "v3.0.4"`